# How to handle exceptions in a nice way?

Tags: c#, exception, do-while

I am trying to write a simple Console App, where I have a User class that looks like this:

```
class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

My goals is to get an input from the user for every property, but I want to check whether the user input
meets specific criterias. For example: when to user tries to enter a value for the Name property, I want to check whether or not the entered value starts with an uppercase letter, contains digits, is less than fifty characters, etc. and if the entered value is not valid, then I throw an exception and ask the user to try again, if it is valid, then we move onto the next property and so on.

My problem is that I can not figure out how to simplify this process, because what happens if I have a property that has to meet a hundred criterias.

Is there a simple way to check if the user input meets a lot of criteria and if not, I throw an exception, show a random error message and after that the user can try again.

Comment: Take a look at data annotations.
https://www.infoworld.com/article/3543302/how-to-use-data-annotations-in-csharp.html

Comment: "My problem is that I can not figure out how to simplify this process, because what happens if I have a property that has to meet a hundred criterias."  Then you'll have a lot of code that validates that input.  This isn't unusual.  The more "bullet proof" your code is, the longer it's going to be.  What you might be looking for, though, is [Regular Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference).

Comment: If you have hundred criterias, then you must test hundred criterias. There is no way to simplify it. You can use the `ErrorProvider` component on the Form together with the `IDataErrorInfo` interface in the data classes. Works nicely, since it does not interrupt the user with error messages. Displays an error indicator next to the TextBoxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One very simple way would be to create a dictionary of ValidationCriterias and corresponding Error Messages for any given class. Since its user input validation checks, I would just throw a valid friendly error message, instead of exception, since such errors were already anticipated.

The following code runs all the validation criterias, even though if any single fails and at the end outputs all the error messages in a pipe separated string.
If at least a single criteria fails , the function will return false.

```
   public class User
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }

    public class ValidateProps<T> where T: class
    {
        public static bool RunRules(Dictionary<Expression<Func<T, bool>>, string> lst, 
                                    T myObj, 
                                    out string errorMessages)
        {
            errorMessages = "";
            bool isSuccess = true;
            foreach (var l in lst)
            {
                if (l.Key.Compile()(myObj) == false) isSuccess = false;
                errorMessages += l.Key.Compile()(myObj) == true ? "" : "|" +l.Value;
                
            }
            errorMessages = errorMessages.Trim('|');
            return isSuccess;
        }
    }

    // Example Usage
    User u = new User() { Name = "dd23dd", Age = 100 };
    Dictionary<Expression<Func<User, bool>>, string> dict1 = 
                new Dictionary<Expression<Func<User, bool>>, string>()
                    { {x => Char.IsUpper(x.Name.ToCharArray().ElementAt(0)), "Error Message 1" },
                    {x => !(x.Name.Any(char.IsDigit)), "Error Message 2"},
                    };

     string errorMsgs = "";
     bool n1 = ValidateProps<User>.RunRules(dict1, u, out errorMsgs);
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the answer I was looking for!